# What is a replacement for Metamask in React App?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, web3-providers

I have an app on react that works great with Metamask but in the real world nobody has to install Metamask and I don't know how to create transaction without Metamask.

is there any way to create a transaction in-app without Metamask?

Comment: I am developing an Ethereum wallet in C++, if interested I can share with you some of my libraries to send transactions, or the entire source code of the wallet, when it is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow user to input private key into your app (only use the private key in client side for secure purpose) or for more secure you can support user using cold wallet like trezor or ledger nano s.

Comment: is there any service which i can generate mnemonic like wallets?

Comment: I think we can use this js lib to generate mnemonic https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39/blob/master/index.js

Comment: should i be full node to push transaction ?

Comment: basically yes; you need to signed and send tnx to a full node; a kind of light client is now in development also https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol

Comment: as you are signing the tranactions, you can use any public service, etherscan api, infura, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-web3-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-web3-provider). There is an example in documentation how to use it with a light-wallet without MetaMask installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this new project: https://fortmatic.com

It's an alternative to MetaMask without requiring end-users to download a Chrome extension (users can login passwordlessly with SMS). I just got into the alpha and started playing around with it, and so far looks promising, pretty good docs and integrates well with web3